# Python Google Calendar API get reminders

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

Hi I was trying to fetch reminders from google calendar api for a certain date range i.e from today till two days after today. But unfortunately when i call the reminders it gives me an IndexError. Please help me out with this. Thanks in advance. Iam attaching the code below followed by the error

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests
import calendar
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
import pickle

class Calendar(Frame):                 
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Calendar, self).__init__(bg='black')
        self.calendars()
        self.reminders()

    def calendars(self):    
        cal = calendar.month(2019,10)
        self.calendarlb = Label(self, text=cal, font="Helvetica 12", bg='black', fg='white')
        self.calendarlb.pack(side=TOP, anchor=N, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    def reminders(self):
        scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
        #flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client_secret.json", scopes=scopes)
        #credentials = flow.run_console()
        #pickle.dump(credentials, open("token.pkl", "wb"))
        credentials = pickle.load(open("token.pkl", "rb"))
        service = build("calendar", "v3" , credentials=credentials)
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
        diff = datetime.timedelta(2)
        Maxtime = now + str(diff)
        result = service.calendarList().list().execute()
        calendar_id = result['items'][1]['id']
        result_new = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id, timeMin=now, timeMax=Maxtime).execute()
        result_newer = result_new['items'][0]['summary']
        result_newer1 = result_new['items'][1]['summary']
        result_newer2 = result_new['items'][2]['summary']
        result_newer3 = result_new['items'][3]['summary']
        #titlelb = Label(self, text="To-do List", font="Helvetica 30", bg='black', fg='white')
        #titlelb.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)
        result_newer1lb = Label(self, text=result_newer1, font="helvetica 15", bg='black', fg='white')
        result_newer1lb.pack(side=TOP,anchor=N)
        result_newer2lb = Label(self, text=result_newer2, font="helvetica 15", bg='black', fg='white')
        result_newer2lb.pack(side=TOP,anchor=N)
        result_newer3lb = Label(self, text=result_newer3, font="helvetica 15", bg='black', fg='white')
        result_newer3lb.pack(side=TOP,anchor=N)
        #self.after(1000,self.reminders)
```

Error: -

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "[...]\Python36\SmartMirror\SmartMirror2.py", line 218, in w = FullscreenWindow() 
File "[...]\Python36\SmartMirror\SmartMirror2.py", line 204, in init self.calendar = Calendar(self.bottomFrame) 
File "[...]\Python36\SmartMirror\SmartMirror2.py", line 149, in init self.reminders() 
File "[...]\Python36\SmartMirror\SmartMirror2.py", line 170, in reminders result_newer = result_new['items'][0]['summary'] IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2):

Close-read your stack trace:

```
line 170, in reminders result_newer = result_new['items'][0]['summary'] 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The `IndexError` means that the script is attempting to index into a list (`result_new['items'][0]`) but that in this case that list is empty.

Re-run the script and inspect the contents of `result_new['items']` before line 170 to see how you might want to adjust the way the result object is unpacked.